# Strange:two same code ,one goes well ,but the other showe error, i've checked for many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## two completely same coding,but one goes well,the other one doesn't work

### error message

/Users/kevin/rails101/app/views/groups/index.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^ /Users/kevin/rails101/app/views/groups/index.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' /Users/kevin/rails101/app/views/groups/index.html.erb:28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrhuB.png)

here is the one showes error

```
<div class="col-md-12">


 <div class="group">
    <%= link_to("New group", new_group_path, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right") %>
  </div>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td><%= link_to(group.title, group_path(group)) %></td>
        <td><%= group.description %> </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to("Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"%>
        <%= link_to("Delete", group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default",
        method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} )%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

the other one goes well:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="group">
    <%= link_to("New group", new_group_path, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right") %>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Description</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @groups.each do |group| %>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td><%= link_to(group.title, group_path(group)) %></td>
          <td><%= group.description %></td>
          <td>
              <%= link_to("Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default")%>
              <%= link_to("Delete", group_path(group),    class: "btn btn-sm btn-default",
                          method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } )%>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the parenthesis here:

```
<%= link_to("Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"%>
```

it should be

```
<%= link_to("Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing parenthesis in this line:

```
<%= link_to("Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"%>
```

It should be:

```
<%= link_to("Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default")%>
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept either my answer or Serj's answer as they both provide the correct solution.

Comment: what could i do for you?it seemed that

Comment: Check out [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).